# How to use Parallel.For for image processing in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I'm processing some images in a for loop based on the number of ROI's present in an image. But if I have 4 ROI's the for loop processes the 4 ROI's one after the other like its supposed to, which is time consuming as my processing takes time. I have read that there is a parallel for loop in C# which can process all 4 ROI's(conditions) together. I tried but unable to understand how to use it.
My current for loop code is :

```
   for(int i = 0; i < imgROIcount; i++)
       {
         Image<Gray, byte> processimg = temp.Clone();
         if (cbThreshold == 1)
             {
                if (txttype.text == "Auto")
                   {
                      CvInvoke.Threshold(processimg , processimg , 0, 255, ThresholdType.Otsu);                        
                   }
                else if (txttype.text == "Manual")
                   {
                       processimg = processimg .ThresholdBinary(new Gray(this.tbocrthreshold.Value), new Gray(255));
                   }
             }
        }
```

I tried :

```
    Parallel.For(0, imgROIcount, i => {
         Image<Gray, byte> processimg = temp.Clone();
         if (cbThreshold == 1)
             {
                if (txttype.text == "Auto")
                   {
                      CvInvoke.Threshold(processimg , processimg , 0, 255, ThresholdType.Otsu);                        
                   }
                else if (txttype.text == "Manual")
                   {
                       processimg = processimg .ThresholdBinary(new Gray(this.tbocrthreshold.Value), new Gray(255));
                   }
             }
         });
```

But it does not run, the whole method is shown in green and then the application exits on continuing.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-parallel-for(system-int32-system-int32-system-action((system-int32-system-threading-tasks-parallelloopstate))))?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I have read the docs. I understand that parallel for does not processes the loop in a sequential manner, it does random processing which is Ok for me. But I dont understand how to frame the loop syntax. Whatever I try it doesnt work.

Comment: What "ROI" means?

Comment: Its "Region Of Interest", Meaning there are 4 selected areas in an image I need to process.

Comment: I don't see you are using the `Parallel.For`. You'd better search for an example.

Comment: Yes, thats because I dont understand how to use it(how to frame the parallel.for syntax).

Comment: As far as I can see you are never using loop variable, `i`, in your loop, and it does not look like you are saving the resulting `processimg` anywhere. So I would highly recommend ensuring your code works as intended using a regular loop before trying to do things in parallel.

Comment: I have not shown the remaining process here where I push the result image into a public image and more, its more than 150 lines. The regular for loop works obviously.

Comment: Your posted `Parallel.For` looks syntactically correct. But your loop body still makes no sense. `Processimg` should only be valid inside the scope of the loop, and I see no other result being produced. Keep in mind that parallel code needs to be *thread safe*, if you are unsure what this implies I would recommend spending a few days studying the topic before doing anything with multiple threads.

Comment: @JonasH : Thank you for your help. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a cross-thread processing issue. Store the values from the UI, such as `txttype.Text` into local variables before calling `Paralle.For()`.

```
string tt = txttype.Text;
var tcr = this.tbocrthreshold.Value;

Parallel.For(0, imgROIcount, i => {
     Image<Gray, byte> processimg = temp.Clone();
     if (cbThreshold == 1)
         {
            if (tt == "Auto")
               {
                  CvInvoke.Threshold(processimg , processimg , 0, 255, ThresholdType.Otsu);                        
               }
            else if (tt == "Manual")
               {
                   processimg = processimg .ThresholdBinary(new Gray(tcr), new Gray(255));
               }
         }
     });
```

and so on for the remaining values accessed inside the loop. Since it is run on separate threads it cannot access any UI values directly. Best to keep local values before the loop starts and use only local variables inside the loop.

PS. Keep with naming conventions in terms of capitalizations (Methods and Properties start with capital letters) and fields and variables with lower case. This helps us understand what is what. For example `txttype.Text` vs. `txttype.text`